# Bootstrap 3.3.7, how to place a pic to one side and columns to the other in grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My issue is getting the image to the left (has to be responsive and there are rows above and below this section) and this sideRow to the right. It's in Bootstrap 3.3.7 and is part of a modal. (This currently does not work properly inside or outside of a modal.)

```
<div class="row"><!---Main Row--->
<!---pic--->
  <div class="row"><!---pic row--->
   <div class="col-xs-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://wiki.toramonlineguildalliance.com/images/e/e4/Colon-Land.png" alt="image">   
   </div><!---c6--->
  </div><!---picRow--->
<!---pic--->
<!---stats--->
<div class="col-xs-6>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="position:relative;left:-10px;text-align:center;">Level 3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="position:relative;right:10px;text-align:center">21 Hp</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="position:relative;left:-10px;text-align:center;">Earth Elemental</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="position:relative;text-align:right;">40</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" style="position:relative;right:20px;text-align:left;">Atk</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="position:relative;text-align:right;">40</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="position:relative;right:24px;text-align:left;">MAtk</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="position:relative;text-align:right;">40</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="position:relative;right:20px;text-align:left;">Def</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="position:relative;text-align:right;">30</div>
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="position:relative;right:24px;text-align:left;">MDef</div>
 </div><!---stats side row--->
</div><!---col6 stats side--->
<!---stats--->
<div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div> 
</div><!---main row--->
```

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/z6v492tw/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your image at the left and the rest of the code at the right?
if it's the question, just modify 2 div class

```
<div class="row"><!---pic row--->
 <div class="col-xs-6">
```

for

```
 <div class="row col-xs-6"><!---pic row--->
 <div class="">
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Dan! I have been stuck on this for days! That worked perfectly! 